# pandoc filter in lua and walk_block

Tags: lua, pandoc

I'm trying to apply a LUA filter that would only alter the body of a document, leaving the Metadata untouched. And it's harder than I thought.

The filter should prepend and append text to inline elements as well as block elements. If it works for the inline element, here `Code`, it fails for the block element `CodeBlock`.

```
function Pandoc(doc)
  blocks = {}
  for k,block in pairs(doc.blocks) do
    table.insert(blocks, pandoc.walk_block(block, {
      -- Doesn't work!?
      CodeBlock = function(el)
        return {
          pandoc.Para({pandoc.Str("Before")}),
          el,
          pandoc.Para({pandoc.Str("After")})}
      end,
      -- Works!
      Code = function(el)
        return {pandoc.Str("Before"), el, pandoc.Str("After")}
      end,
    }))
  end

  return pandoc.Pandoc(blocks, doc.meta)
end
```

What am I missing? Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `walk_block` and `walk_inline` process the *content* of an element, not the element itself.

If `wrapper` is your filter table, this should do what you want:

```
function Pandoc (doc)
  local div = pandoc.Div(doc.blocks)
  local blocks = pandoc.walk_block(div, wrapper).content
  return pandoc.Pandoc(blocks, doc.meta)
end
```

An alternative solution would be to save and restore the metadata, like so:

```
local meta = {}
return {
  { Meta = function(m) meta = m; return {} end },
  wrapper,
  { Meta = function(_) return meta; end },
}
```

This is probably more efficient, as serializing/deserializing only metadata and Code/CodeBlock elements is likely faster than doing the same for the full document.

Comment: I had issues with the `pandoc.Div` solution. Although the man filters solution works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: sorry, forgot to get the blocks back by accessing the `div`'s  `.content` field. First solution should work now, too.