# Pandoc Lua Filter restructure JSON output

Tags: lua, pandoc

Having a collection of documents built on same template, I want to use pandoc to extract content structure by header using a filter, of preference a [lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html). For making things clearer, is it possible to emit the following json from this markdown content:

```markdown
# Header 1

## subject 1.1

abc

## subject 1.1

def

# Header 2

ghi
```

to that kind of json for further treatment:

```json
[
  {
    "h1": "Header 1",
    "content": [
      "## subject 1.1",
      "abc",
      "## subject 1.1",
      "def"
    ]
  },
  {
    "h1": "Header 2",
    "content": [
      "ghi"
    ]
  }
]
```

I don't know how to accumulate headers and content for returning it at end of parsing. I might be confused by Pandoc API. Pandoc might not be the right tool for that kind of parsing but is it doable? For this example, I don't want to go deeper than H1, but it could with real documents.

**Follow up**

I modified this [SOF pandoc-filter-in-lua-and-walk-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350104/pandoc-filter-in-lua-and-walk-block?rq=1) code. The snippet is OK for my learning purpose, but how to to make `Pandoc(doc)` returns the expected JSON?

```
json = require("json")

-- get key-value table length
function tablelength(tbl)
    local count = 0
    for _ in pairs(tbl) do
        count = count + 1
    end
    return count
end

-- what this function does and returns is unclear
function Pandoc(doc)
    -- required at end of function (1), but cannot find how to use it
    blocks = {} 

    -- result table
    local res = {}
    -- temp table
    local tbl = {}

    for _, block in pairs(doc.blocks) do
        if block.t == "Header" then
            if block.level == 1 then
                if tablelength(tbl) > 1 then
                    table.insert(res, tbl)
                end
                tbl = { content = {} }
                tbl["h1"] = pandoc.utils.stringify(block)
            else
                table.insert(tbl.content, pandoc.utils.stringify(block))
            end
        else
            table.insert(tbl.content, pandoc.utils.stringify(block))
        end
    end

    -- after last block
    table.insert(res, tbl)

    -- print to stdout. Works if
    print(json.encode(res))
    -- can save to a file if needed as a side effect
    -- file = io.open("result.json", "w")
    -- file:write(json.encode(res))
    -- file:close()

    -- what to use for returning the JSON array of objects?
    return pandoc.Pandoc(blocks, doc.meta) -- (1)
end
```